# Safari Browser gives Error: Unhandled Promise Rejection: Invalid Date

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am using React calendar, Link given as below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar

I am storing date in MySQL database in UTC Format. and when I fetch the start date and end date in JSON format I convert then into date object and show them as the selected date on the calendar.
It works fine on chrome and firefox, but on safari browser it gives error.
Please Help.

**Here is My Code:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import API from './API';
    import Calendar from 'react-calendar';


    class MyListingDetails extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                locationId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locationId')),
                location: { locationAmenities: [], locationRules: [], locationImages: [], user: {} },
                startDate: '',
                endDate: '',
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {

            API.getLocatonDetails(this.state.locationId, 0).then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    response.json()
                        .then(
                            (result) => {
                                console.log("location Detail", result.data.loactions)
                                this.setState({
                                    location: result.data.loactions,
                                    startDate: new Date(result.data.loactions.startDate),
                                    endDate: new Date(result.data.loactions.endDate),
                                })
                            });
                }
                else {
                    response.json()
                        .then(
                            (result) => {
                                alert(result.message)
                            }
                        );
                }
            });
        }

handleStartDate(date) {
        this.setState({ startDate: date})
    }

    handleEndDate(date) {
        this.setState({ endDate: date})
    }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="form-group calendar_box">
                        <div className="tab-content">
                            <div id="start_time" className="tab-pane active">
                                <Calendar minDate={new Date()} onChange={this.handleStartDate.bind(this)} value={this.state.startDate} />
                            </div>
                            <div id="end_time" className="tab-pane">
                                <Calendar minDate={new Date()} onChange={this.handleEndDate.bind(this)} value={this.state.endDate} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default MyListingDetails;
```

**Date format From Backend like**

```
"startDate": "2019-09-25T18:30:00.000+0000",

"endDate": "2019-09-30T18:30:00.000+0000",
```

Both are stored in the UTC Format

Comment: safari has issue with Date format, use momentJs or something else otherwise send milliseconds from server

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't seem to like the date format provided.

```
// doesn't work
Date.parse("2019-09-25T18:30:00.000+0000")

// works
Date.parse("2019-09-25T18:30:00.000")
```

If you're able to do so, maybe strip the timezone offset (`+0000`) from the response before working with it.